# mod_rewrite and SEF is not working on joomla

Tags: joomla1.5, joomla-sef-urls

I am using joomla 1.5.2. When the mod_rewrite and SEF is enabled I have different url and it is not working. For example:

```
https://sampleprojects.com/component/jobboard/buy (SEF and Apache mod_rewrite enabled)
https://sampleprojects.com/index.php?option=com_jobboard&view=buy&Itemid=2(SEF and Apache mod_rewrite disabled)
```

I have SSL on my site, and I have .htaccess file also. The problem is that the Itemid is not added in the SEF URL.

Comment: Did you already search the SEF table for the new URL https://sampleprojects.com/component/jobboard/buy or the old URL https://sampleprojects.com/index.phpoption=com_jobboard&view=buy&Itemid=2 ?

Comment: I don't know the exact answer for your case. But I know that the SEF URL are stored in a mysql table. So maybe you can find those URLs you were talking about in the table and maybe that will put you in the right direction of finding the answer. 

(I know there are a lot of maybes, but that's why I'm giving a comment instead of an answer..)

Comment: I doubt that it is because the Itemid is not added, it shouldn't be.

Comment: @SørenBeckJensen I think Itemid is not added when the SEF enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Itemid is never added to the SEF Url and it should not be either. The Itemid indicates what menu link you clicked on to get there. It is primarily used for highlighting the active menu link when viewing a page.

If you for instance have two different menu's both linking to the same page, they will have two different Itemid's but essentially be the same page. This is why SEF url's strip the Itemid, because it would create duplicate content item issues in Google.

Just to prove I am a credible source. I am the lead developer on the [Joomla Component Creator](http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/) and have been developing Joomla web sites since version 1.0.